# Removing old users’ home directories from Linux server

Tags: linux, filesystems, find, ls, home-directory

We have an NFS server with thousands of users home directories. I did a lot of searching and man page reading and I can't seem to figure this out.

I want to remove the home directories of the users that are no longer with us. Basically anyone that hasn't logged in and made changes to their home folders in over a year.

The snag i keep hitting is every tool i see (ls, find, etc) will give me the listing on the last time a directory was modified but not the contents inside.

Take the user Joe for example.

`/data/Users/joe/Windows# ls -lt
    drwxrwx---+  2 1079 nhsstaff    4096 2008-07-31 15:13 Cookies`

So judging from this output you would think this folder had not been access since July 7th 2008.

But when you look inside the directory:

```
`root@smb0:/data/Users/joe/Windows/Cookies# ls -ltr
-rwx------+ 1 1079 nhsstaff    92 2009-02-17 03:16 default@sun[1].txt
-rwx------+ 1 1079 nhsstaff    86 2009-02-17 03:16 default@ig[1].txt
-rwx------+ 1 1079 nhsstaff   136 2009-02-17 03:16 default@google[1].txt
-rwx------+ 1 1079 nhsstaff   104 2009-02-17 03:16 default@dell[1].txt
-rwxrwx---+ 1 1079 nhsstaff 32768 2010-04-26 07:53 index.dat`
```

You can see files have been changed since April 26th 2010.

So to sum up, i need a way to search and sort when the last time a home directory was used.

Comment: It might help if you searched [the right site `;-)`](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Can you instead check your logs and find out for sure the last time they logged in rather than scanning over your whole filesystem and hoping they _modified_ something recently?

Comment: I hope I don't see a story in the news in the next week or two about an NHS contractor losing lots of data...

Comment: Agree with @sarnold, you don't want to delete a user's homedir just because they've only written to files in `/tmp` and `/var/mail`.

Answer (score 1):

run this command:

```
find /data/Users -mtime +365 |  awk '{print $1}' | cut -f2 -d"/" | sort\
    | uniq -c | awk '{print $2}'
```

This set of commands will give you list of all those users, who have not modified their home folders for more than a year.
If you want script to auto delete those folders through script, I can provide it as well.